# Inductive definition of $\infty$-category

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

I am having trouble comparing the usual picture of strict $\infty$-categories as categories with $k$-morphisms for each $k\geq 0$ with their inductive definition.

If one lets $0Cat := Set$, strict $n$-categories are defined inductively by
$$
(n+1)Cat = (nCat)Cat.
$$
With this definition, objects of $nCat$ have a set of $k$-morphisms for each $k\leq n$, and for each $k>0$ there is a composition of $k$-morphisms.

Moreover, for each $n$ there is a functor $i:nCat\to (n+1)Cat$ adjoining $n+1$ morphisms for $n$-morphisms trivially:
$$
\hom(f,g) =
\begin{cases}
\{\emptyset\}\quad\text{ if } f=g
\\
\emptyset\quad\text{ otherwise.} 
\end{cases},
\text{ for all n-morphisms } f,g.
$$

Strict $\infty$-categories are defined by taking the colimit below:
[image: dsa]

I can't see why does this definition implies the standard description of $\infty$-categories i.e. there are $k$-morphisms for each $k\geq 0$.

Comment: Where did you find this definition?  I would think you would take a limit of forgetful functors in the opposite direction, not the colimit you describe.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+n-category "The category $Str\omega Cat$ of strict $\omega$-categories can then in turn be defined as a suitable colimit of the categories $nCat.$"

Comment: However, I must guess the forgetful functors are adjoint to the inclusion functors described above, so there may be no difference.

Comment: No, there is a big difference.  The colimit will give you only "bounded" $\infty$-categories, those where all morphisms above a certain dimension are identities.  (Unless the colimit is meant to be taken in some different sense from the most obvious one, but I don't know what that would be...)

Comment: Why? The chain does not truncate at any $n\leq \infty$. I have rewritten the diagram in the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Well any object of the colimit (in the usual sense) is an object of some stage of the colimit, so an object of $nCat$ for some $n$, which is the description Eric made

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an explicit construction of filtered colimits in Cat, if so that would certainly solve your question (following Maxime Ramzi's intuition)

Comment: @Intergalakti Filtered colimits in Cat work perfectly. The set of objects is the filtered colimit in sets, and similarly for the sets of morphisms. In particular a colimit like this is just a union.

Comment: Thank you all, I see now why taking a colimit above doesn't work. After reversing arrows and taking a limit, I guess one could see $n$-morphisms of a strict $\infty$-category by looking at the projection $\infty Cat\to nCat$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see $\infty$-categories as a colimit of $n$-categories, you need to take some kind of a "completed" colimit. For instance, you can see your functors as functors of locally presentable categories and take the colimit in there. In any case this just amounts to taking the limit in the ordinary sense of the right adjoints, so it's probably indeed more natural to think about a limit.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now why the usual colimit doesn't work here. However, I don't see how swapping arrows and changing to a limit would enlight these strict $\infty$-categories as categories with a morphisms $k$ for each $k\geq 0$.

Comment: I guess one could see $n$-morphisms of a strict $\infty$-category by looking at the projection $\infty Cat\to nCat$?

Comment: @big-lion That’s exactly it.

Comment: One final question: we should be able to see $n$-categories as $\infty$-categories with only identity $k$-morphisms for $k>n$. Such a functor $nCat\to\infty Cat$ doesn't arise naturally from the limit, would we have to take such a completed colimit to create it?

Comment: @big-lion You can get that functor using the universal property of the limit and the cone formed by the inclusions $nCat\to mCat$ for $n\leq m$ and the forgetful functors for $m<n$.